# If $A,B$ are sets and $B$ is finite, and there is an injection $f:A \to B$, then $A$ is finite and $card(A) \leq card(B)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am stuck with proving this statement for a while.

Prop. If $A,B$ are sets and $B$ is finite, and there is an injection $f:A \to B$, then $A$ is finite and $\operatorname{card}(A) \leq \operatorname{card}(B)$

This is my proof:

Let $A,B$ sets. Suppose that $B$ is a finite set, and there is an injection $f:A \to B$.

If $A=\emptyset$ then $A$ is a finite set and $\operatorname{card}(A) \leq \operatorname{card}(B)$.

If $A \neq \emptyset$, since $B$ is a finite set, there exists a bijection $g: B \to [n]$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $\operatorname{card}(B) = n$.

Also because we suppose there is an injection $f:A \to B$ we have an injection $g \circ f : A \to [n]$. So $A$ is also a finite set and $\operatorname{card}(A) \leq n$, and hence $\operatorname{card}(A) \leq \operatorname{card}(B)$.

The part I am confused is: If I can argue that $A$ is a finite set just because I have an injection $g \circ f : A \to [n]$.
Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I think that the cardinality of  A has to be equal to B

Comment: You really should give us your definition of a set being finite and the ordering of cardinalities. For the standard definitions there is essentially nothing to do.

Answer (score 1):

Since The function $f:A\to B$ is an injection then $f^{-1}$ exists for this function (because each value of $B$ has been mapped via only one value of A) and B is finite so the mapping $B \to A$ and so $A$ is definitely finite.

Now the second part Since $f$ is an injection each element of A has been mapped to only one element of B and that's true for the reverse mapping also then suppose if Cardinality($A$)$>$Cardinality($B$);
According to function definition ,each element of $A$ has to be mapped to something so more than one element are mapped to the same element which is against the fact in question($f$ is an injection) so Cardinality($A$) $\le$ Cardinality($B$)

Answer (score 0):

A set $S$ is finite iff there exists a bijection $f:S\to$ $\{1,2,3,\ldots, n\}$ for some $n\in \mathbb{N}$

So, as for above, you know that there is a bijection between $A$ and its image in $g\circ f$, which should be enough for you to finish the problem.

Comment: Can you explain how I know g∘f : A - > [n] is bijective?

Comment: I didn't say it is bijective. There is a bijection between $A$ and a subset of $[n]$

Comment: uh.. okay what is "there is a bijection between A and its image in  g∘f" supposed to mean?

Comment: $A$ is in bijection with its image in $g\circ f$, do you know what that means? It means, that $A$ maps bijectively to the subset of $[n]$ that is precisely $f\circ g (A)$

Comment: oh I get it now.... thank you so much!!!

Comment: Hey, happy to help. Glad you get it!

Comment: idk if u would see this comment, but just in case u see it... um but how can we assume subset of [n] is finite? don't we need to prove it too?

Comment: Yeah, you'll need to prove that a subset of a finite set is finite. 

Here's a good proof: 
https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Subset_of_Finite_Set_is_Finite